# Explode string and join the new part

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$date = '10/10/2014'
```

What I want to do is to get a part of the string and change to another value, like:

```
$parts = explode('/', $date);
if($parts[0] == '10'){
    $parts[0] = '31';
}
```

How can I join the $parts[0] in the $date?

```
echo $date;
```

Should return 31/10/2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `implode` method

```
$date = '10/10/2014'

$parts = explode('/', $date);

if($parts[0] == '10'){
    $parts[0] = '31';
}

$date = implode('/', $parts);
```

learn about `implode` on [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`impode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$date = '10/10/2014';
$parts = explode('/', $date);
if($parts[0] == '10'){
    $parts[0] = '31';
}
$date = implode('/',$parts); // $date equals '31/10/2014'
```